# Does autowiring a derived class also ensures the base class is setup?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, spring-annotations

3 classes `Test, Base, Derived`

In the `Base` class I have a a few fields (say `A and B`) which are Autowired and also a constructor.

In the `Derived` I have the implementation of the abstract methods.

When I autowire the `Derived` class in Test will the fields of the `Base` class (`A and B`) be setup? Will the constructor of the `Base` class be called?

```
Test() {
   @Autowired
   Derived derived;
}

@Component
Base() {
  @Autowired 
  A a;
  B b;

  public Base() {
     //Do Something
  }
}

@Service
Derived() extends Base {

}
```

Comment: Yes, it will work as you expect. Why don't you just try it and see?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'm not a Spring IOC user, I'm a guice IOC user. So if you'll allow me to make some reasonable assumptions about Spring, and assuming your example simply contains some clerical errors

If you had

```
class Base{
    @Autowired A a;
    @Autowired B b;

    public Base(){
        // doConfigurationOfOtherFields
    }
}

@Service
class Derived extends Base{
    //as per the language spec, if you don't include a constructor
    //one is effectively auto-generated for you.
    //and if you have a superclass it's param-free ctor will be called automatically
    //meaning regardless of whether or not you typed this in source code
    //effectively you get
    Dervied(){
        super();
    }
}

Derived instance = iocContainer.resolve(Derived.class);
```

Then yes, both `a` and `b` instances should be created and set by Spring. and the constructor of `Base` will be called as the first action taken by the (implicit) `Derived` constructor.

I do not believe spring will set assign values to `a` and `b` *before* the constructor is called (unless its using obgenisis), so those values will be assigned after the constructor is called.